# getting an error. TypeError:object of type 'file' has no len()

Tags: python

```
import sys
sudlist= open(sys.argv[1],'r')
def check_sudoku(sudlist):
```

## makes a list of each number to be found

```
   ` x = range(1, len(sudlist)+1)`
```

## assigns all the rows to a flat list

```
rows = [[row[i] for row in sudlist] for i in range(len(sudlist))] 
    z = range(len(sudlist))
    for num in x:
        for pos in z:
            if num not in sudlist[pos] or num not in rows[pos]:
                return False
    return True
d=check_sudoku(sudlist)
print(d)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `len` on file object. 
Read its content first using either `.readlines()` method or call `list()` on it.

```
sudlist = list(sudlist)
x = range(1, len(sudlist)+1)
```

Comment: hey thanks!! it worked and i have got another error can u please solve it "if num not in sudlist[pos] or num not in rows[pos]:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"